# How to increment id without auto increment?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-sequence

I have a table with id column as a number which have meanings. Different types of accounts start from different ranges. E.g Organisation 10000 <-> 100000, users 1000000 <-> 1kk. How can i properly increment ids on insert (with possible concurrency problem)?

Comment: If you are using java for inserting data then you can use synchrozed block and calculate max first of id and then can insert the data, if you want to insert only through query then db row level lock needs to be taken care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were doing this in Oracle's table server, you would use [different `SEQUENCE` objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF51138) for each type of account.

The [MariaDB fork of MySQL](https://mariadb.org/) has a [similar kind of SEQUENCE object](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-functions/), as does [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). So if you were using MariaDB you would do something like this.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS org_account_id MINVALUE=10000 MAXVALUE=999999;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS user_account_id MINVALUE=1000000;
```

Then to use a sequence in place of autoincrement you'll do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, col1, col2) 
         VALUES (NEXTVAL(user_account_id), something, something);
```

In MySQL you can emulate sequence objects with dummy tables containing autoincrement ids. It's a kludge. Create the following table (one for each sequence).

```
CREATE TABLE user_account_id (
     sequence_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_id`)
);
ALTER TABLE user_account_id AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

Then issue these queries one after the other to insert a row with a unique user id.

```
INSERT INTO user_account_id () VALUES (); 
DELETE FROM sequence WHERE sequence_id < LAST_INSERT_ID();
SET @id:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO tbl (id, col1, col2) 
         VALUES (@id, something, something);
```

After your insert into the dummy table, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a unique id. The DELETE query merely keeps this dummy table from taking up too much space.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a normal sequence-based `bigint` column. Then, on `SELECT`, add the base for the appropriate account type to the column.

Comment: What if i do this in trigger before insert? Or it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into emp(emp_code,emp_name,join_date,designation,birth_date,gender,mobile) values((select max(emp_code)+1 from emp),?,?,?,?,?,?)")
```

This query will definitely help..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).